# Uses for Windows 7 fingerprint reader

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, fingerprint, biometrics

I just bought a Thinkpad T410s. It comes with a finger print reader. I'm using it on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit for loging in.

Anyone have any other practical and useful ways to use it? For example, for loging in to websites or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lenovo has a password saver utility that works with the fingerprint reader. On my (old) Thinkpad T60 it's called the ThinkVantage Fingerprint Software. It works a lot like the password manager in Firefox. It saves usernames and passwords for web sites, and submits them automatically. You will have to scan your fingerprint once for the first site, then it's automatic after that.

To use it (on Windows XP)

- Click Start > All Programs > ThinkVantage > ThinkVantage Fingerprint Software
- Click Fingerprints to enroll your fingerprints.
- Click Settings to configure how and when it will submit passwords.

Comment: You can also configure particular sites to require your fingerprint everytime it fills in the details, which is useful for higher security for banking.  I wish I could have something like the ThinkVantage Password Manager on my desktop computer as well.

Comment: I only see this one http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=tvan-eapfpr and, unfortunately, no version for Windows 7.

Comment: @Nimmy: I use it on Windows 7 with my X200s.  That page is old, for old models.  Type the model number on the right column of that page or click on 'Detect my system', which should take you to all the relevant ThinkVantage software for your ThinkPad.

Comment: @Nimmy: If you are not sure what you are doing, just install ThinkVantage System Update. That should give you an easy way to install all the drivers and ThinkVantage software you want when you run that. It's a lot easier than doing it manually.  However, you should have all this stuff installed already.

Comment: I installed everything on my ThinkVantage System Update including "ThinkVantage Fingerprint Software". I got to the start menu and there is no entry for "ThinkVantage Fingerprint Software"".I do however see "Fingerprint Rreader" control panel. I enrolled my fingerprints but I do not see any option to use it for anything *other* than Windows login.

Comment: @paradroid any update? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Nimmy: You'll find it in the Start Menu when you search for `Password Vault`.  It's a bit fiddly to get used to, but once you know how to configure the different levels of security options, it's great.  It could do with some improvement though and, annoyingly, does not work with Google Chrome yet.

Answer (score 2):

Lastpass supports windows 7 fingerprint readers. I think that that might be your best option. I love lastpass and the security is excellent. 256 bit AES encryption transmitted over SSL then reencrypted on their end. This would allow you to have a master password for all of your browsers linked to your fingerprint reader.
http://www.lastpass.com

Answer (score 1):

Many things that require authentication, like web sites, can be configured to use the fingerprint scanner.

Comment: How would you configure that?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from authentication, some fingerprint readers allow you to start a program just by swiping a finger.

Comment: any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @surfmadpig: Depends on your fingerprint reader, check their manual.